# How to block LINE stamp spam

Tags: spam, line

In the Android app [LINE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(software)), since yesterday, I started receiving spam messages like this one (below the advertisment):

[image]

The spammer (with the name `LINEスタンプ` in this case, can also be `LINEで応募`) appears in my messages list despite not being my friend.

I have deleted the conversation, but more messages have kept coming yesterday and today.

Is there any way to block or report the spammer?

- I would rather not open the message.
- The long-press menu does not show any block option, only "Delete" which I tried already.

Answer (score 0):

The `LINEスタンプ` account is automatically added (with your permission nor knowledge) to your friends (in the `Official accounts` tab) when you download any stamp collection:

[image]

Long-press it and select `Block`:

[image]

Then delete the conversation. It should not reappear this time.

[image]

The same idea applies for groups that turned spammy: Rather than tapping `Hide` or `Delete` in `Chats`, tap `Leave` in `Home`>`Groups`.